# Paypal Getting error regarding redirect_url

Tags: ios, paypal

I am using the latest version of the iOS Paypal SDK (2.0.1) and am getting the following error when making a single payment.

```
payPal SDK: Request has failed with error: VALIDATION_ERROR - The payment information is invalid. Please correct and submit again. (400) | PayPal Debug-ID: 5a103a01e6d3a | Details: (
{
    field = "redirect_urls";
    issue = "This field required when payment_method is 'paypal'";
}
```

So it appears I need to set some redirect_urls. I have not seen any mention of how/where I should be setting these in the PayPal documentation (for iOS)

Can someone shed some light on this for me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

We've seen this rather surprising error message before, if when making a payment one specifies the same PayPal account for both the payer and the merchant (payee).

When you make test payments using the PayPal iOS SDK, be sure to log into a PayPal account different from your merchant account.

(And yes, our server team is looking into fixing the error message that is returned in this situation.)

Comment: Thank you Dave! To expand on Dave's answer... If your merchant account is for example paypal@yoursite.com and your test account is myEmail@yoursite.com you will probably get this error (at the time of writing). Creating a new test account with something different than your merchant domain .. ex (myemail@gmail.com) fixes the problem.